# How to invoke MSBuild from PowerShell using & operator?

Tags: powershell

I've just tested this on PowerShell v1.0. Setup is as follows:

```
 Id CommandLine
 -- -----------
  1 $msbuild = "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe"
  4 $a = "C:\some\project\or\other\src\Solution.sln /target:Clean /target:Build"
```

.

**This line fails with an unintuitive error message:**

```
 Id CommandLine
 -- -----------
  5 & $msbuild $a
```

.

**This line fails because & expects the first argument to be the command itself.**

```
 Id CommandLine
 -- -----------
 10 & "$msbuild $a"
```

.

**This line works:**

```
 Id CommandLine
 -- -----------
 16 cmd /c "$msbuild $a"
```

.

Please explain. I'm more interested in why the & syntax isn't working, than an MSBuild-specific workaround.

Comment: I suggest using a helper cmdlet such as [`Invoke-MSBuild`](http://sedodream.com/2014/07/19/IntroducingPSBuildAnImprovedInterfaceForMsbuildexeInPowerShell.aspx) instead of calling MSBuild directly.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The issues you are seeing results from PowerShell parsing arguments.  In the first example, when PowerShell sees $a it passes it as a single parameter msbuild.  We can see this using the echoargs utility from [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com):.

```
PS> $a = "C:\some\project\or\other\src\Solution.sln /target:Clean /target:Build"
PS> & echoargs $a
Arg 0 is <C:\some\project\or\other\src\Solution.sln /target:Clean /target:Build>
```

The second example is even worse because you are telling powershell to invoke "$echoargs $a" as the command name and it isn't a valid command name.

The third line works because CMD.exe gets the expanded form of "$echoargs $a" as a single argument which is parses and executes:

You have a couple of options here.  First I do it this way:

```
PS> & $msbuild C:\some\project\or\other\src\Solution.sln `
    /target:Clean /target:Build
```

The other option is to use Invoke-Expression like so:

```
PS> Invoke-Expression "$msbuild $a"
```

In general I try to be very careful with Invoke-Expression particularly if any part of the string that gets invoked is provided by the user.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I'm guessing the strings didn't parse correctly for some reason.  The solution by @PeterSeale below worked for me

Answer (score 49):

Ugh.

```
$collectionOfArgs = @("C:\some\project\or\other\src\Solution.sln", 
    "/target:Clean", "/target:Build")
& $msbuild $collectionOfArgs
```

This works. & takes a collection of arguments, so you must split up strings containing multiple arguments into a collection of string arguments.

Comment: Great... Worked for me with a log list of arguments due to logging.

Comment: Great solution! Along with the explanation provided by @keith-hill this makes perfect sense.

Comment: #blessYou  This was k1ll1ing me.

Comment: To avoid error "msbuild.exe is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet", msbuild path must not be enclosed in double quotes. This is a working declaration of $msbuild variable: `$msbuild = "$MSBUILD_PATH\msbuild.exe"`

Answer (score 4):

You can also try using the free [Invoke-MsBuild powershell script/module](https://github.com/deadlydog/Invoke-MsBuild). This essentially gives you an Invoke-MsBuild PowerShell cmdlet that you can call instead of trying to invoke the msbuild.exe manually yourself.

Answer (score -2):

That works well for me:

```
PS> cmd.exe /c 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\msbuild.exe' /target:Clean /target:Build 'C:\some\project\or\other\src\Solution.sln'
```