# Run MSBuild from PowerShell can't find project file

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I am running a simple MSBuild in PowerShell like this

```
$solution = 'E:\VS2017Projects\CmdBuildTest\CmdBuildTest.sln'
$params = '/p:Configuration=Debug /t:Clean /t:Build'
$msbuild = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
$argument = $solution + ' ' + $params
#Test-Path $solution
& $msbuild $argument
```

Although the commented out Test-Path does return true, I am always getting following error:

> MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.

When I tried to run MSBuild.exe directly in command line to build with exact same file path and arguments it worked as expected. Now wondering what I'm doing wrong in PowerShell?

Comment: So if you replace `&` with `write-host` and copy-paste the result into same Powershell prompt, the build works OK?

Comment: Probably classical parameter passing problem, first try what's described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/869867/128384

Comment: @stijn Thanks. That does solve the problem