# Powershell script to publish vs projects to file system

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, msbuild, publish

i have around 25 projects in one solution. and everytime i modified those project i have to build and publish to local File system. and IIS pointing to those published folder. 
Im thinking if there is any way i could create a powershell script that can publish all these project so i don't have to do it manually.

things i have tried with no luck. as powershell throws error msbuild not found.

```
msbuild C:\Development\myService /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile /p:Configuration=Release  /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.9.7
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried fully qualifying the path to msbuild. X or Y not found simply means you do not have it in your system, user or PowerShell paths.

Comment: l think is that you did not put the path of `msbuild.exe` to powershell, and since you use vs2017,  I think you should use the whole path like `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`

Answer (score 1):

> things i have tried with no luck. as powershell throws error msbuild
>   not found.

**First**, thanks to **postanote** for sharing the useful info.

**Since** it turns out the error **msbuild not found**, l think you did not specified the full path of `MSBuild.exe` or input the wrong path so that **Powershell** couldn't find `msbuild`.

**Solution**

You can try this:

```
$msbuild="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
& $msbuild C:\xxx\xxx\xxxx\xxxx.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile /p:Configuration=Release  /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.9.7
```

**Note** that you should **rebuild** all your projects and then run this powershell script. Besides, since you have many projects to publish, you should write multiple commands for each project like the second command as shows(every `xxxx.pubxml` belongs to its own project).

**In addition**, you can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869278/how-to-invoke-msbuild-from-powershell-using-operator) to get more detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem that most of us have with release management.

If you check
[Building a simple release pipeline in powershell](https://devblackops.io/building-a-simple-release-pipeline-in-powershell-using-psake-pester-and-psdeploy/)
by Brandon Olin this may be a great help.

Perhaps you could make an adaption that would suite your needs and as an added benefit only update the project/s that changed.
Check it out it maybe worth a try!